# Marklogic|NodeJS API - Query on a specific categorie "properties"

Tags: node.js, marklogic, nosql

I have a json document in my DB that looks like this :

```
{
"uri" : "/me/myself/and/bd1e0f91656bfc713eb6560eeaad7ad1.json",
"category" : "content",
"format" : "json",
"versionId" : "14697362595356370",
"contentType" : "application/json",
"contentLength" : "1938",
"collections" : ["http://me.myself.com/collectionA"],
"properties" : {
    "relatives" : ["/me/myself/and/B.json", "/me/myself/and/A.json"]
},
"content":{}
```

}

I'm trying to get all documents that have a specific relative in the properties:

```
qb.where(
   qb.scope(
    qb.property('relatives'),
    qb.word("/me/myself/and/B.json"),
    qb.fragmentScope('properties')
))
```

But i keep getting a large set of document that doesn't fit the query.

Any idea how to do this using the Marklogic NodeJS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qb.where(
  qb.propertiesFragment(
    qb.term('/me/myself/and/B.json')
  )
)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that look like they might be problems. The first is `qb.fragmentScope('properties')`. This tells MarkLogic to look in the [document's properties](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties#id_19516), rather than the document's content. That doesn't look like what you meant, given your sample JSON document.

The second problem is the word query -- "/me/myself/and/B.json" is likely being broken up into its constituent words (me, myself, and, B, json), which are then matching in other documents. You want to match exactly what's there, so try a value query:

```
qb.where(
  qb.scope(
    qb.properties('properties'),
    qb.value('relatives', '/me/myself/and/B.json')
  )
)
```

Note that the `qb.scope` and the `qb.properties` are to restrict the search to just match the value when it appears in `relatives` under a `properties` JSON property. This is different from the JSON property-versus-content point made above.

Comment: Im actually looking to query in the document's properties. As you can see in my sample example, content is empty.